# Pickle over +str() function

Tags: python, pickle

What is the difference between the `Pickle` module and the `+str()` function? I just finished writing the following piece of code

```
def orf(codons):
seqlist = []
flag = False
start = ['ATG']
    stop= ['TAA','TGA','TAG']
    for i in codons:
    if i in start:
        flag = True
            if flag == True:
        seqlist.append(i)
    if i in stop:
        flag = False
return seqlist

frame1 = string
codons = [frame1[i:i+3] for i in range (0, len(frame1),3)]
one = orf(codons)
seq1 =''.join(one)
output1 = 'Length of 1st open reading frame is:'+str(seq1)
#seq1 =''.join(one)
seq_list.append(seq1)
length1 = len(seq1)
output_1 = '\nSize of 1st open reading frame is:'+str(len(seq1))
length_list.append(length1)
out.write(output1)
out.write(output_1)
```

I use the `+str()` function to get the function `(orf (codons))` in the form of a string. Is this possibe using `Pickle`. I did read a python tutorial but couldnt understand a word of what it meant. I would be great if you could work around my code.

Comment: There's no `+str()` function; you're adding two strings together; your  predefined string, and the output of `str()`.

Comment: oh! But then i was always getting an error when ever I was directly calling the function like
    `output_1 = '\nSize of 1st open reading frame is:'orf(codons)`

I had to assign diff variables and then use the +str() to print the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `+str` function.

The code snippet you show contains the expression `'Length of 1st open reading frame is:'+str(seq1)` which is composed of a string, the `+` operator, and a call to the class `str`.

Pickle is a module which allows (most) python objects to be serialized to files (or streams).

Answer (score 0):

The `str` function does a very different thing than the `pickle` module.

`str` converts any Python object into a string, usually in a human-readable or "friendly" way (there's also the `repr` function which does so with a bit less friendliness and more focus on machine-readability). So `str([1,2,3])` returns the string `'[1, 2, 3]'`. Custom classes can control how `str` converts them to strings by overriding the special `__str__` method.

`pickle` on the other hand is designed for serialization of Python objects. That can also involve converting the objects into strings, but it is completely focused on machine readability, rather than human interpretation. In fact, the strings you get from many forms of pickling (there are several different protocols) contain binary values that can't be directly viewed as text. (`pickle` also has various hooks that custom classes can tie into, but they're a bit more complicated than `__str__`.)

For your situation, `pickle` doesn't seem like what you want. Using `str` will let you convert integers, lists and other objects to strings for printing. Strings, including both literal strings you create using quotation marks and those you get from `str` can be concatenated using the `+` operator (though you might want to consider [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) instead). Note that if you're already converting your lists to strings using the `str.join` method there's no need to run `str` again on the result (as you seem to be doing to `seq1` in the code in your question).